# set access control headers for same domain requests

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm using restangular to consume an api hosted on the same server as the angular files. All requests to the api are getting Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors. I've tried altering headers in the config

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

and updating angular/restangular. Is there a way to set the headers for same domain requests using restangulars setdefaultheaders method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error that your are getting is due to Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policies of your web server.

The resources being on the same server is not enough. They have to be served by the same host.
Is important to understand that `api.mydomain.com` is a different from `www.mydomain.com`.
Also having a different port (`api.mydomain.com` vs `api.mydomain.com:9000`) makes it a different host.

Check that the response of the response of your server contains the HTTP header:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: api.yourdomain.com"
```

To check how to enable a CORS on your web server check this useful website: [enable_cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/)

You can read more about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: so basically I have to set the headers on the requests and responses of both to Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: Trying to put some more info on @fabrizioM's answer, you only have to enable `CORS` on your server side. You have to do this not by any special header on your requests, but from your api. So, for instance if you use `Django` as your backend and probably `Tastypie` or `Django Rest Framework`, a very good and easy option is to install the `django-cors-headers` package. I hope this adds up to fabriziom's answer and not messing you up more.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment nikolasd. I thought the issue was with the javascript so interesting to hear that its to do with the api. So I added wsgi cors to my pyramid api and now the error reads 'Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.'. Is this credentials flag something I also need to configure on the backend?

Comment: ok so I was able to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the domain serving the frontend which I guess is better than using the wildcard security wise. Thanks for the input!